# Using named pipe including command on php syntax error

Tags: php, bash

```
$ cat a.php
<?php
system("echo <(ls)");
```

this script.

```
$ php a.php
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I execute the script.
But a syntax error occered.

```
$ echo <(ls)
/dev/fd/63
```

success on bash.
I dont know what to do.

Comment: Have you tried using [`shell_exec()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) instead?

Comment: Process substitution is a bash feature; I'm pretty sure `system()` is using plain sh.

Comment: Quibble: `<(ls)` is not a ["named pipe"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe). A named pipe is a persistent object which exists as a naned directory entry in the filesystem. (Hence, "named" pipe.) `/dev/fd/63` is not a persistent name in a filesystem, despite its appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

---

```sh
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

This error typically comes up for non-bash shells, which don't support `<()` expression pipes. Even when sh is bash, it'll run in a compatibility more where process substitution is not available.

It will work fine with bash.

```sh
$ echo <(ls)
/dev/fd/63
```

---

### Solutions

#### Solution #1

Script should always be run with bash with `/bin/bash -c`.

```php
system('/bin/bash -c "echo <(ls)"');
```

#### Solution #2

Via executable script.

***execute.sh***

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo <(ls)
```

***a.php***

```php
<?php 

exec('execute.sh');
```

Comment: Thank you very much !
I was convinced.